# Get value of most recent date

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I want to get the value of col B for the most recent date.  The number of rows may change... i.e. oct isnt always the most recent date.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1):

With data in cols **A** and **B**, use:

```
=index(B:B,match(max(A:A),A:A,0))
```

[image]

As you see from the example, we don't even have to sort the data.

Answer (score 1):

On dates u can use the MAX function. If you wrap this inside a VLOOKUP the MAX will get you the searchkey and the returns the value next to it.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A1:A10),A1:B10,2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

proper way:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, MAX(A:A)
```

[image]

or:

```
=FILTER(B:B, A:A=MAX(A:A))
```

[image]